# Check whether the content in one row equals to the first appeared value, if so, record ID: how to achieve this in R automatically?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have people's trip records as a data frame in R. Which looks as below:

```
   t_participant_id t_destination_PostCode tripReasonString tripSequence
1               304                   1082             work            1
2               304                   1000             work            2
3               304                   1000             work            3
4               304                   1000            other            4
5               304                   1000            other            5
6               304                   1082            other            6
7               304                   1082             home            7
8               362                   1070         shopping            1
9               362                   1070             work            2
10              362                   1070             work            3
11              362                   1070         shopping            4
12              362                   1180             home            5
13              362                   1070          leisure            6
14              362                   1180             home            7
15              482                   2800             work            1
16              482                   2800             work            2
17              482                   1020             home            3
```

Basically, `t_participant_id` is a person's unique ID, `tripReason` is the reason for people's trip, and the `t_destination_postcode` is the area that they are going to (for instance, in row 1, person `304` go to area `1082` for `work`).

Different people have different numbers of trips during one day (person `304` and `362`has 7 trips in total, whereas person `482` has 3). I would like to filter out the person that the `t_destination_PostCode` for the trip purpose `work` is the same as other work trips under this person's activity chain.

In short, for person `304`, his first work trip is at line 1, and going to the area `1082`. The next work trip is at line 2, and going to the area `1000`. So I know he is not the person I would like to filter out. However, for person `362`, he has the first `work` activity at `tripSequence == 2`, heading to `1070`. The next `work` trip is at `tripSequence` 3, and also to 1070. No other work trips in the activity chain anymore. So in this case, we would like to filter out person `362`, and record the first work `tripSequence`, which is 2.

So the final result should be a data frame that says

```
t_participant_id    firstWorkTrip
             362                2
             482                1
```

I really don't want to do this manually but not sure how can I achieve this in R. Thanks very much for your help in advance!

Here is the reprex for the dataframe

```
test <- data.frame(list(t_participant_id = c(304L, 304L, 304L, 304L, 304L, 
                                             304L, 304L, 362L, 362L, 362L, 362L, 362L, 362L, 362L, 482L, 482L, 
                                             482L), t_destination_PostCode = c(1082L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 
                                                                               1000L, 1082L, 1082L, 1070L, 1070L, 1070L, 1070L, 1180L, 1070L, 
                                                                               1180L, 2800L, 2800L, 1020L), tripReasonString = c("work", "work", 
                                                                                                                                 "work", "other", "other", "other", "home", "shopping", "work", 
                                                                                                                                 "work", "shopping", "home", "leisure", "home", "work", "work", 
                                                                                                                                 "home"), tripSequence = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                           3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>%
  filter(tripReasonString == "work") %>%
  group_by(t_participant_id) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(t_destination_PostCode) == 1) %>%
  summarize(first_work_trip = min(tripSequence))
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   t_participant_id first_work_trip
#              <int>           <int>
# 1              362               2
# 2              482               1
```

Comment: I never thought this is that easy! Thanks Gregor :)